# Publish or initialize audio only stream in licode

Tags: node.js, media, licode

I need to initialize audio only stream (audio: true, video: false).
But when I pass the options (audio: true, video: false) in erizo.stream I'm unable to hear the voice of published stream.

I tried different cases like: (none is working)

1. did not pass video option when subscribe stream.
2. tries with different browser like firefox.
3. did not pass option minVideoBW when publish the stream.

Does anyone have idea about this problem ?